# woocommerce rest api 401 unauthorized

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

when i trying to get data from My API 
i got error 401 unauthorized 
Note that it was working well two days ago there no any change in api or in my code

i'm trying also  with basic Auth not working

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the tokens in this way and try

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=your_key&consumer_secret=your_secrtkey
```